# Docker: MySQL container bind host mysqld socket

Tags: php, mysql, docker, unix-socket

I am using Docker 19.03.8 and want to setup two containers:

- The first is a MySQL container which bind mounts the mysqld socket from the host.
- The second one is a PHP container which needs to access the database via the MySQL container.

Both containers share the same network via the `networks` statement. (I can not bind mount the mysqld socket directly into the PHP container, as the MySQL versions are different, therefore the MySQL container).

This is my *docker-compose.yml* file:

```
...
database:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/tmp/mysql.sock
...
```

The *Dockerfile* for MySQL:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.20
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And the *my.cnf* file contains:

```
...
[mysql]
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
...
```

Unfortunately I get this error message from the MySQL container:

```
2020-05-20T11:30:04.708067Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2020-05-20T11:30:04.708406Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ?
2020-05-20T11:30:04.709083Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

The MySQL container starts with no errors, if I leave out `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` from the `[mysqld]` section in *my.cnf*. But if I then try to connect to the database from the PHP container (`mysql -h <what I specified in the networks statement> -u <user> -p <password>`) I just get an empty database. So I assume it uses the default socket (*/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock*).

I don't understand why this is not working, I would be really grateful if anyone could give me a hint.

Comment: mysql creates the socket so you need to do a socket path rather than a socket itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Where do I have to put the socket path? I mean in my.cnf I need to specify the socket location. I could bind mount the whole /var/run/mysqld path but that would make no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a TCP connection for this.  Configure the PHP container to connect to the Compose service name (`database`) and default MySQL port (3306) for the database container.  Do not try to use a Unix socket here.

This setup should work with the out-of-the-box `mysql:8` and Docker Compose configurations.  You do not need a custom `my.cnf` or Compose `networks:`, `container_name:`, `links:`, or other options.

---

The important detail in the setup you show is that the MySQL daemon must create the socket file itself.  If you really want to do this using a Unix socket, you need to bind-mount the directory containing the socket file; you can't bind-mount the socket itself.  (You could also in principle use a named volume here.)

```yaml
# Not the preferred path: mount a directory instead of a file
volumes:
  - ./shared_tmp:/tmp
```

With the setup you show, you'll hit the following sequence of events:

1. Docker tries to set up the `database` container.
2. Docker sees `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` doesn't exist on the host, so it creates an empty directory there and mounts it into the container.
3. When the MySQL daemon starts up, it tries to create a socket at `/tmp/mysql.sock`, but there is already a (empty) directory there.

In general it's better to avoid trying to communicate between containers via the filesystem.  In addition to complications like these, there are frequently user-permission issues, and this setup limits your ability to run on multi-host setups like Docker Swarm and Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough: The actual database I want to access lies on the host system and not in the MySQL container. But I want to access the database from the PHP container through the MySQL container. The MySQL container shouldn't create a new socket, it should just use the host socket.

The more I write about it, the less the setup makes sense to me.

Comment: For that setup, you don't need a MySQL container, which would run a second server.